# How to unload/remove body components in Box2D?

Tags: c++, box2d

I want to know how to release/clear/remove a variable. (specifically b2BodyDef, b2Body, b2FixtureDef, b2PolygonShape types.)

I've heard there's a keyword called `delete`, guessing by it's name it may have something to do with this subject?

---

I'm totally new to these things and I've just heard that there's a way to do this.

I might be wrong and there isn't a way to do this at all.

Which also means that I have no idea if I should include code or what information I should include at all :P

Comment: delete is the c++ operator you use to free up any memory you allocated with the new operator. I have no experience with Box2D, but this is most likely not what you are looking for. I think the method suggested by 11mad11 suffices for freeing the memory as well; Box2D will most likely do this for you, though it may not even be allocating this using new. I suggest reading how (dynamic) memory allocaiton in c++ works.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know if its the same for c++ but in java its

```
world.destroyBody(body);
```

and after in java we do `body = null;`
in c++ do like this : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/
to free all memory that we dont need anymore.

Comment: It exists in c++ too, this only removes the body from the world though, how would I go about clearing/releasing the variables?

Comment: in java for release a variable we use `body = null;`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/
try this.

Comment: Ok, that seems to be the answer. Could you turn all of this into a answer? So I can mark it? :P

Comment: Another thing, according to a error NULL can only be used on int types. What if my type isn't an int? How should I define it without assigning memory to it? Just by not assigning something to it?

Comment: im not sure to understand your question(im french) but in java all variable can be null. and the answer is the link?

Comment: I think the answer is the link, at least if it does what I think it does. Let me explain what I want more ; I want to clear my variables memory so that they don't use unnecessary memory, will ( free(variableName); ) do that? If yes, the link is the answer to my question :)

Answer (score 1):

When allocating memory for an object in C++ using `new`, you must later deallocate it with `delete` or you will likely have a memory leak. In C, `malloc` corresponds with `free`.

When it comes to Box2D, `world.CreateBody` and `world.DestroyBody` handle `b2Body` creation and clean up for you. Additionally, you do not need to allocate the `b2BodyDef`, `b2FixtureDef`, and `b2PolygonShape` objects on the heap using `new`. Instead, create them on the stack like so:

```
b2BodyDef bodyDef;
bodyDef.position.Set(center.x + size/2, center.y + size/2);

b2Body* body = world.CreateBody(&bodyDef);

b2PolygonShape box;
box.SetAsBox(size / 2, size / 2.0f);

b2FixtureDef fixtureDef;
fixtureDef.shape = &box;
fixtureDef.friction = 0.3f;

body->CreateFixture(&fixtureDef);
```

Notice that no usage of `new` is necessary.

Finally, be careful when using `SetUserData` to store pointers to your own custom data in `b2Body` and `b2Fixture` using `new`. You must iterate over the body's fixtures and call `delete` on any user data that you stored in there.

You can learn more about the C++ stack vs. heap here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap